# Unable to implement CURL command inside a IF statement within cmd in windows 10

Tags: curl, cmd

I am trying to make a simple web page checker that I can do certain actions based on the status that the page returns (e.g. 200, 301, 302 and 404).

I have tried many variations of the code to get it to work and I will post down below the version I thought made the most sense and got me the farthest.

Test #1

```
REM Ask for intializing info
set /p start="Which page do you want to scan?: "

REM We will use Microsoft's website as the test site for this example.
set WEBSITEURL = https://www.microsoft.com/%start%

REM Start scan, only get header info to save bandwidth, I can not use grep since I am on a windows computer
if (curl -i https://www.microsoft.com/%start% | findstr '200') ; then
    printf "Great the page exists!"
        else
            REM for the sake of the example we will just do 1 if else here and only check for 200, else lets just say the page does not exist
            printf "The page does not exist"
fi
```

The result here was: *"https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store" was unexpected at this time.*

Test #2:
Ok so since that did not work let me test the curl out in just a blank cmd without running it inside a script.

```
curl -i https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store | findstr "301"
```

The above test worked just fine and reported back a 301, this is great! but the issue is that the code is not working when running in a script and inside an IF statement, I just keep running into errors and can never get passed this error. Any Idea on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for the assist and I hope you all have a great day.

Comment: The issue seems to be that you're confused about which shell you want to use. [tag:windows-10] uses `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` as its 'shells', `bash` is a [tag:unix] based 'shell'. As you're using the [[tag:cmd]] tag, we'll assume you're using that as the 'shell', and therefore need to use the `cmd.exe` command syntax, not the `bash` syntax, you appear to have used as the basis for some of the code you have posted.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, thank you! I updated the title of the question to make sure people know I am trying to run this in cmd in windows 10 :)

Comment: Well you've clarified that you're not looking for assistance for [[tag:bash]], but that doesn't explain why you're still using its syntax, `if () then x else y fi`. To learn how to use [[tag:cmd]] syntax, open `cmd.exe`, type the command followed the default help option, `/?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output presented.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Read more: [`https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/)

Give a try by using `curl` command output redirecting to `findstr` with `/beginning of a line` and apply operator `&&` (`return 0`) and supressing any output `>nul`

```batch-file
curl .... | findstr /b HTTP/1\.1.*200 >nul && echo\ zOk!
```

- ## One simple way:

```batch-file
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem :: Ask for initializing info (string input)
set /p "_url=Which page do you want to scan?: "

rem :: Using Microsoft's website as the test site
set "_websiteurl=https://www.microsoft.com/!_url!"

rem :: Start scan, only get header info to save bandwidth, I can not use grep since I am on a windows computer and if match (&&) goto to :Next
2>&1 %__APPDIR__%curl.exe -i "!_websiteurl!"|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /b HTTP/1\.1.*200 >nul && echo\Great the page exists! && goto=:Next
2>&1 %__APPDIR__%curl.exe -i "!_websiteurl!"|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /b HTTP/1\.1.*404 >nul && echo\The page does not exist && goto=:Next
2>&1 %__APPDIR__%curl.exe -i "!_websiteurl!"|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /b HTTP/1\.1.*301 >nul && echo\This page is moved permanently && goto=:Next
2>&1 %__APPDIR__%curl.exe -i "!_websiteurl!"|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /b HTTP/1\.1.*302 >nul && echo\This page is moved temporarily && goto=:Next

rem :: If any string output from each one curl command above does not match for any [200|301|302|404] string, then got the output from the server
echo\None found: [200^|404^|301^|302] & 2>&1 %__APPDIR__%curl.exe -i "!_websiteurl!"|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /b HTTP.1\.*[0-9] >con: & goto=:Next

:Next
rem./ do more here... & endlocal
```

- Input and output web site **https://www.microsoft.com/store**

```batch-file
Which page do you want to scan?: store
This page is moved temporarily
```

- Input and output web site **https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/**

```batch-file
Which page do you want to scan?: inbox
None found: [200|404|301|302]
HTTP/1.1 440 Login Timeout
```

- Input and output web site **https://live.com**

```batch-file
Which page do you want to scan?: mail
This page is moved permanently
```

---

- ## One non simple way:

```batch-file
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color 0A & title <nul & title %~nx0

set "_bat=%~dpnx0" && cd /d "%~dp0"
set "_msg_error=Incorrect input^!! Press any key to continue..."
set "_code_http=200=Great the page exists^!!,301=Page moved Permanently"
set "_code_http=!_code_http!,302=Page moved temporarily,404=Page does not exist"

:LOOP
set /p "_string=Which page do you want to scan?: " || <nul (
<con: set /p "'=!_msg_error!" & echo;& goto=:LOOP) || goto=:LOOP

if exist %__APPDIR__%curl.exe set "_curl=%__APPDIR__%curl.exe" && goto=:check
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('2^>nul "%__APPDIR__%where.exe" /r "%~dp0." curl.exe
')do <con: set "_curl=%%~i" && goto=:CHECK

:ERROR
if not defined _curl (
     echo\ERROR: "cUrl.exe" was not found in your %%path%% or in "%~dp0?.."^!!
     %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal & goto=:EOF
     ) else goto=:OTHERS
    
:CHECK
set "_string=https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/!_string!"
(for %%i in ("!_code_http:,=","!")do for /f tokens^=1-2delims^=^= %%I in ('echo\%%~i'
)do 2>nul "!_curl!" -i "!_string!"|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /b HTTP/1\.1.*%%~I && (
    <con: set /p "'=!_string! status: %%I %%J" <nul & set "_answer=%%~I" && set "_resp=%%~J" && (
    goto=:NEXT ))) || goto=:ERROR

:NEXT
echo\!_answer!|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe 30[1-2] >nul && for /f tokens^=2 %%u in (
'^<con: "!_curl!" -i "!_string!"^|find/i "location"')do set "_url_to=%%~u"
if defined _url_to <con: set /p "'=!_string! --^> !_url_to!" <nul 

rem :: You can to continue your batch script task and using this variables bellow
rem :: !_answer! == 200, 301, 302 or 404 // any other server response goto=:ERROR
rem :: !_string! == https://www.microsoft.com concatenated with user string input
rem :: !_url_to! == the shortner url expanded to the url redirected by 301 or 302
rem ::   !_resp! == server response sting set in _code_http 2nd token delimiter =
rem ::   !_curl! == curl saved with a fully qualified path name: %path% or %~dp0.
endlocal & goto :EOF

:OTHERS
pushd %__APPDIR__% && for /f tokens^=2* %%i in (
'2^>^&1 "!_curl!" -i "!_string!"^|findstr.exe /b HTTP.1\.1.
')do 2>&1 findstr.exe /bx %%~i "!_bat!" || set "_output=%%~i %%~j" && popd

if defined _output echo\Unknown or unlisted output: !_output!
<con: rem./&& %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF

:: ---------------------------------------------------------- ::
::   HTTP response status codes for using in label :OTHERS    ::
::   Official / unofficial : IIS * AWS Elastic Load Balancer  ::
::   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes  ::
:: ---------------------------------------------------------- ::

100 Continue
101 Switching Protocols
102 Processing / Checkpoint
103 Early Hints
104 Unassigned
105 Unassigned
106 Unassigned
107 Unassigned
108 Unassigned
109 Unassigned
110 Unassigned
111 Unassigned
112 Unassigned
113 Unassigned
114 Unassigned
115 Unassigned
116 Unassigned
117 Unassigned
118 Unassigned
119 Unassigned
120 Unassigned
121 Unassigned
122 Unassigned
123 Unassigned
124 Unassigned
125 Unassigned
126 Unassigned
127 Unassigned
128 Unassigned
129 Unassigned
130 Unassigned
131 Unassigned
132 Unassigned
133 Unassigned
134 Unassigned
135 Unassigned
136 Unassigned
137 Unassigned
138 Unassigned
139 Unassigned
140 Unassigned
141 Unassigned
142 Unassigned
143 Unassigned
144 Unassigned
145 Unassigned
146 Unassigned
147 Unassigned
148 Unassigned
149 Unassigned
150 Unassigned
151 Unassigned
152 Unassigned
153 Unassigned
154 Unassigned
155 Unassigned
156 Unassigned
157 Unassigned
158 Unassigned
159 Unassigned
160 Unassigned
161 Unassigned
162 Unassigned
163 Unassigned
164 Unassigned
165 Unassigned
166 Unassigned
167 Unassigned
168 Unassigned
169 Unassigned
170 Unassigned
171 Unassigned
172 Unassigned
173 Unassigned
174 Unassigned
175 Unassigned
176 Unassigned
177 Unassigned
178 Unassigned
179 Unassigned
180 Unassigned
181 Unassigned
182 Unassigned
183 Unassigned
184 Unassigned
185 Unassigned
186 Unassigned
187 Unassigned
188 Unassigned
189 Unassigned
190 Unassigned
191 Unassigned
192 Unassigned
193 Unassigned
194 Unassigned
195 Unassigned
196 Unassigned
197 Unassigned
198 Unassigned
199 Unassigned
200 OK
201 Created
202 Accepted
203 Non-Authoritative Information
204 No Content
205 Reset Content
206 Partial Content
207 Multi-Status
208 Already Reported
209 Unassigned
210 Unassigned
211 Unassigned
212 Unassigned
213 Unassigned
214 Unassigned
215 Unassigned
216 Unassigned
217 Unassigned
218 Unassigned / This is fine
219 Unassigned
220 Unassigned
221 Unassigned
222 Unassigned
223 Unassigned
224 Unassigned
225 Unassigned
226 IM Used
227 Unassigned
228 Unassigned
299 Unassigned  
300 Multiple Choices
301 Moved Permanently
302 Found (Previously "Moved temporarily")
303 See Other
304 Not Modified
305 Use Proxy
306 Switch Proxy
307 Temporary Redirect
308 Permanent Redirect
309 Unassigned
310 Unassigned
311 Unassigned
312 Unassigned
313 Unassigned
314 Unassigned
315 Unassigned
316 Unassigned
317 Unassigned
318 Unassigned
319 Unassigned
320 Unassigned
321 Unassigned
322 Unassigned
323 Unassigned
324 Unassigned
325 Unassigned
326 Unassigned
327 Unassigned
328 Unassigned
329 Unassigned
330 Unassigned
331 Unassigned
332 Unassigned
333 Unassigned
334 Unassigned
335 Unassigned
336 Unassigned
337 Unassigned
338 Unassigned
339 Unassigned
340 Unassigned
341 Unassigned
342 Unassigned
343 Unassigned
344 Unassigned
345 Unassigned
346 Unassigned
347 Unassigned
348 Unassigned
349 Unassigned
350 Unassigned
351 Unassigned
352 Unassigned
353 Unassigned
354 Unassigned
355 Unassigned
356 Unassigned
357 Unassigned
358 Unassigned
359 Unassigned
360 Unassigned
361 Unassigned
362 Unassigned
363 Unassigned
364 Unassigned
365 Unassigned
366 Unassigned
367 Unassigned
368 Unassigned
369 Unassigned
370 Unassigned
371 Unassigned
372 Unassigned
373 Unassigned
374 Unassigned
375 Unassigned
376 Unassigned
377 Unassigned
378 Unassigned
379 Unassigned
380 Unassigned
381 Unassigned
382 Unassigned
383 Unassigned
384 Unassigned
385 Unassigned
386 Unassigned
387 Unassigned
388 Unassigned
389 Unassigned
390 Unassigned
391 Unassigned
392 Unassigned
393 Unassigned
394 Unassigned
395 Unassigned
396 Unassigned
397 Unassigned
398 Unassigned
399 Unassigned
400 Bad Request
401 Unauthorized
402 Payment Required
403 Forbidden
404 Not Found
405 Method Not Allowed
406 Not Acceptable
407 Proxy Authentication Required
408 Request Timeout
409 Conflict
410 Gone
411 Length Required
412 Precondition Failed
413 Payload Too Large
414 URI Too Long
415 Unsupported Media Type
416 Range Not Satisfiable
417 Expectation Failed
418 I'm a teapot / Page Expired
419 Unassigned / Page Expired
420 Unassigned / Method Failure / Enhance Your Calm
421 Misdirected Request
422 Unprocessable Entity
423 Locked
424 Failed Dependency
425 Too Early
426 Upgrade Required
427 Unassigned
428 Precondition Required
429 Too Many Requests
430 Unassigned / Request Header Fields Too Large
431 Request Header Fields Too Large
432 Unassigned
433 Unassigned
434 Unassigned
435 Unassigned
436 Unassigned
437 Unassigned
438 Unassigned
439 Unassigned
440 Unassigned 
441 Unassigned
442 Unassigned
443 Unassigned
444 Unassigned
445 Unassigned
446 Unassigned
447 Unassigned
448 Unassigned
449 Unassigned
450 Unassigned / Blocked by Windows Parental Controls (Microsoft)
451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons
452 Unassigned
452 Unassigned
453 Unassigned
454 Unassigned
455 Unassigned
456 Unassigned
457 Unassigned
458 Unassigned
459 Unassigned
460 Unassigned * Client closed the connection
461 Unassigned * The load balancer received an X-Forwarded-For
462 Unassigned
463 Unassigned
464 Unassigned
465 Unassigned
466 Unassigned
467 Unassigned
468 Unassigned
469 Unassigned
470 Unassigned
471 Unassigned
472 Unassigned
473 Unassigned
474 Unassigned
475 Unassigned
476 Unassigned
477 Unassigned
478 Unassigned
479 Unassigned
480 Unassigned
481 Unassigned
482 Unassigned
483 Unassigned
484 Unassigned
485 Unassigned
486 Unassigned
487 Unassigned
488 Unassigned
489 Unassigned
490 Unassigned
491 Unassigned
492 Unassigned
493 Unassigned
494 Unassigned
495 Unassigned
496 Unassigned
497 Unassigned
498 Unassigned / Invalid Token
499 Unassigned / Token Required 
500 Internal Server Error
501 Not Implemented
502 Bad Gateway
503 Service Unavailable
504 Gateway Timeout
505 HTTP Version Not Supported
506 Variant Also Negotiates
507 Insufficient Storage
508 Loop Detected
509 Unassigned / Bandwidth Limit Exceeded
510 Not Extended
511 Network Authentication Required
512 Unassigned
513 Unassigned
514 Unassigned
515 Unassigned
516 Unassigned
517 Unassigned
518 Unassigned
519 Unassigned
520 Unassigned
521 Unassigned
522 Unassigned
523 Unassigned
524 Unassigned
525 Unassigned
526 Unassigned / Invalid SSL Certificate
527 Unassigned
528 Unassigned
529 Unassigned / Site is overloaded
530 Unassigned / Site is frozen
531 Unassigned
532 Unassigned
533 Unassigned
534 Unassigned
535 Unassigned
536 Unassigned
537 Unassigned
538 Unassigned
539 Unassigned
540 Unassigned
541 Unassigned
542 Unassigned
543 Unassigned
544 Unassigned
545 Unassigned
546 Unassigned
547 Unassigned
548 Unassigned
549 Unassigned
550 Unassigned
551 Unassigned
552 Unassigned
553 Unassigned
554 Unassigned
555 Unassigned
556 Unassigned
557 Unassigned
558 Unassigned
559 Unassigned
560 Unassigned
561 Unassigned
562 Unassigned
563 Unassigned
564 Unassigned
565 Unassigned
566 Unassigned
567 Unassigned
568 Unassigned
569 Unassigned
570 Unassigned
571 Unassigned
572 Unassigned
573 Unassigned
574 Unassigned
575 Unassigned
576 Unassigned
577 Unassigned
578 Unassigned
579 Unassigned
580 Unassigned
581 Unassigned
582 Unassigned
583 Unassigned
584 Unassigned
585 Unassigned
586 Unassigned
587 Unassigned
588 Unassigned
589 Unassigned
590 Unassigned
591 Unassigned
592 Unassigned
593 Unassigned
594 Unassigned
595 Unassigned
596 Unassigned
597 Unassigned
598 Unassigned /(Informal convention) Network read timeout error
599 Unassigned
```

- ## Input and output:

```batch-file
Which page do you want to scan?: store
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store status: 301 Page moved Permanently
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store --> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/b/home
```

---

**1.** Define the response codes and the respective messages for each one:

```batch-file
200=Great the page exists^!!
```

**2.** Define already populating a pseudo array with these values/string delimited by `,` in double quotation marks, and for the case of using this declaration in two lines, you can concatenate `set "variable=!Variable!,More Values"`

```batch-file
set "_code_http=200=Great the page exists^!!,301=Page moved Permanently"
set "_code_http=!_code_http!,301=Page moved Temporarily,404=Page does not exist"
```

- Variable set to this value:

```batch-file
200=Great the page exists^!!,301=Page moved permanently,301=Page moved temporarily,404=Page does not exist
```

**3.** . You can use the `set /p` command already implementing some control to handle potential errors in the input actions by user, by using operators, `goto` and some error message for using looped `:label`

```batch-file
:LOOP
set /p "_string=Which page do you want to scan? :" || <nul (
<con: set /p "'=!_msg_error!" & echo;& goto :LOOP) || goto=:LOOP
```

**4.** Concatenates the string saved in the input in the variable `string`, already adding the link/site, and at the same time setting the value for the variable `string` to be with the complete link...

```batch-file
set "_string=https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/!_string!"
```

**5.** Considering that the latest versions of Windows 10 already come with `curl.exe` (tar.exe idem), this point verifies the availability of curl in the system folder.
Here it is also considered prone if the user himself has manually added the curl in a version / build that does not have, the code will search the folder and subfolders where the bat was called, and where to find it, it will save the complete path of the executable.

- **Obs.:** If it does not find, go straight to perform the actions of label `:ERROR`

```batch-file
if exist %__APPDIR__%curl.exe set "_curl=%__APPDIR__%curl.exe" && goto=:check
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('2^>nul "%__APPDIR__%where.exe" /r "%~dp0." curl.exe
')do <con: set "_curl=%%~i" && goto=:CHECK
```

**6.** Concatenate the string from the input (`!_string!`) with the link.

```batch-file
set "_string=https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/!_string!"
```

**7.** Use a `for` loop to echo each item in its pseudo arry, using a substring that var turns **`,`** into **`","`** thus composing a usable string in the loop, which will be/stay in use that way:

```batch-file
for %%i in ("!_code_http:,=","!")do...

rem :: the same :: 
for %%i in ("200=Great the page exists^!!","301=Page moved permanently","301=Page moved temporarily","404=Page does not exist")do....
```

**8.** Take the loop variable from the array, where the delimiter `=` will be with the 1st token code, and the 2nd the answers, and join these composing the curl syntax projecting the output for use of the `findstr`, which will search for the code in begin of the line in order to match, if this happens, we have the code in `%%I` and the answer text in `%%J` ...

```batch-file
for /f tokens^=1-2delims^=^= %%I in ('echo\%%~i'
)do 2>nul "!_curl!" -i "!_string!"|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /b HTTP/1\.1.*%%~I && (
```

**9.** The `findstr` received the `curl` output as input to filter/to find the response code (came from 1st loop) but, the `findstr` output itself is not necessary to imitate on the screen, it just matters whether it matched or not, if it did, `findstr return 0` or `return non 0`, and the operator (here `&&`) will take the action to define the variables and go to the label `:NEXT` in case of item handled in the looping of the first `for` is found in execution by `findstr` within the current loop (2nd).

- **Obs.:** If none of the codes in the first token are found with the curl outputs in all those operated in the loop, the action results in going to the label `:ERROR`

```batch-file
                                                                           ...findstr.exe /b HTTP/1\.1.*%%~I && (
<con: set /p "'=!_string! status: %%I %%J" <nul & set "_answer=%%~I" && set "_resp=%%~J" && ( goto=:NEXT ))) || goto=:ERROR
```

**10.** When entering 'NEXT' label, `findstr` will check if in the variable `!_answer!` the stored value is `301` or `302`, where for these values, the respective destinations of the redirectors (`location:`) will be echoed on the screen and the url rersults will be saved in variable `!_url_to!`, handled by the `for /f` only loop if `findstr return 0`, ...

```batch-file
:NEXT
echo\!_answer!|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe 30[1-2] >nul && for /f tokens^=2 %%u in (
'^<con: "!_curl!" -i "!_string!"^|find/i "location"')do set "_url_to=%%~u"
if defined _url_to <con: set /p "'=!_string! --^> !_url_to!" <nul
```

**11.** You can delete all the lines `rem :: ...`, at this point you can use to implement other functions in your batch, when finished, it ends the local set and will jump to the end of the file (`:EOF`), ignoring all the following lines, and ending the script execution...

```batch-file
rem :: You can to continue your batch script task and using this variables bellow
rem :: !_answer! == 200, 301, 302 or 404 // any other server response goto=:ERROR
rem :: !_string! == https://www.microsoft.com concatenated with user string input
rem :: !_url_to! == the shortner url expanded to the url redirected by 301 or 302
rem ::   !_resp! == server response sting set in _code_http 2nd token delimiter =
rem ::   !_curl! == curl saved with a fully qualified path name: %path% or %~dp0.
```

**12.** The `ERROR` label is subject to being called at various points of the code actions conditioned to the results of the executions taken, when it occurs it will check if the culr variable has been defined or not, if culr.exe has not been found, it returns a message stating this and ends the execution.

```batch-file
:ERROR
if not defined _curl (
     echo\ERROR: "cUrl.exe" was not found in your %%path%% or in "%~dp0?.."^!!
     %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal & goto=:EOF
```

**13.** For cases where `curl` has been defined, then execution will continue take place/go on in label `:OTHERS`

```batch-file
     ) else pushd "%__APPDIR__%" && goto=:OTHERS
```

**14.** It is still possible to test if any code answered by the server is different from the elements/values present in the created pseudo array, so it is still possible/valid to try to obtain this response information, confronting with a larger list than just the four codes saved in the array, using findstr to get the answer independent of the elements of the array and more broadly

```batch-file
:OTHERS
pushd %__APPDIR__% && for /f tokens^=2 %%i in (
'2^>^&1 "!_curl!" -i "!_string!"^|findstr.exe /b HTTP.1\.1....
```

**15.** The command type will process the bat file, which contains the widest list of the possible server response

```batch-file
')do findstr.exe /bx %%~i "!_bat!"
```

**16.** If `curl` code output is not in the bat list, there, they can still be added, and the respective code will be echoed in screen

```batch-file
                                        || set "_output=%%~i %%~j" && popd

if defined _output echo\Unknown or unlisted output: !_output!
```

**17.** An indefinite timeout is executed, the `setlocal` is finished and goes straight to the final file, skipping the lines leaving and stopping the execution of the bat immediately.

```batch-file
<con: rem./&& %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

- Output input **storeX**

```batch-file
Which page do you want to scan?: storeX
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/storeX status: 404 Page does not exist
```

- Output input **.**

```batch-file
Which page do you want to scan?: .
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/. status: 200 Great the page exists
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Popd](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)**

  [√] **[Pushd](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)**

  [√] **[Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**